# No thermal stone in survival tab

Tags: dont-starve

I'm on day 18 in Don't starve. With the onset of winter I need to build a heat stone, but when I check the survival tab the stone does not appear there for crafting. It's not even that I can't build it, it just isn't on the tab. I have a shadow manipulator, am playing in sandbox mode and am playing vanilla with no mods. Why can't I build it?

Comment: The important question here is how the heck did you manage to get a shadow manipulator by day 18?!

Comment: @Gamer3001 Pure, unadulterated skill. And probably a great deal of luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Thermal Stone isn't a magic item, it's a normal item. You'll need an Alchemy Engine to invent it, and it'll be the last item in the Survival tab.

You won't even *see* the Thermal Stone in the Survival tab unless you're standing next to a Science Machine, and you won't be allowed to invent it unless you're next to an Alchemy Engine.

You'll need 10 Stones, 1 Pickaxe (even a mostly-worn-out one will do), and 3 flint to craft one. You can find more information on the [wiki page](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Thermal_Stone).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was under the impression that a shadow manipulator was a higher tier research station (in that it would be able to prototype everything an alchemy engine could and more).